# Separate string by numbers and characters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format a string to produce a new string in the correct format:

I have the following strings (left) which should be formatted to match (right):

```
  [ 'xx9999', 'XX-99-99' ],
  [ '9999xx', '99-99-XX' ],
  [ '99xx99', '99-XX-99' ],
  [ 'xx99xx', 'XX-99-XX' ],
  [ 'xxxx99', 'XX-XX-99' ],
  [ '99xxxx', '99-XX-XX' ],
  [ '99xxx9', '99-XXX-9' ],
  [ '9xxx99', '9-XXX-99' ],
  [ 'xx999x', 'XX-999-X' ],
  [ 'x999xx', 'X-999-XX' ],
  [ 'xxx99x', 'XXX-99-X' ],
  [ 'x99xxx', 'X-99-XXX' ],
  [ '9xx999', '9-XX-999' ],
  [ '999xx9', '999-XX-9' ]
```

I have tried the following but cannot get it to work correctly:

```
const formatLp = (userInput) => {
  if (userInput) {
     return userInput.toUpperCase().match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi).join('-');
  }
}
```

This works for some of them, such as `99xxx9` but not others such as `xx9999`

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you only want to add `-` each time between characters that are different, one function iterating through each character will do. This would just as well turn 'AAbb23' into 'AA-BB-2-3' or alike. Do you mean that? Or do you mean to separate numerical and alphabetical? Like 'xx123FG' turns into 'XX-123-FG'?

Comment: Your algorithm is unclear, as I can think of several different algorithms that fit your examples, but would behave distinctly in some different examples

Comment: What are the rules? It's not obvious from the examples you have shown what the requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.replace` twice - once to insert a `-` between 4 repeated digits/non-digits, and once to insert a `-` between digits and alphabetical characters:

```js
const arr = [
  [ 'xx9999', 'XX-99-99' ],
  [ '9999xx', '99-99-XX' ],
  [ '99xx99', '99-XX-99' ],
  [ 'xx99xx', 'XX-99-XX' ],
  [ 'xxxx99', 'XX-XX-99' ],
  [ '99xxxx', '99-XX-XX' ],
  [ '99xxx9', '99-XXX-9' ],
  [ '9xxx99', '9-XXX-99' ],
  [ 'xx999x', 'XX-999-X' ],
  [ 'x999xx', 'X-999-XX' ],
  [ 'xxx99x', 'XXX-99-X' ],
  [ 'x99xxx', 'X-99-XXX' ],
  [ '9xx999', '9-XX-999' ],
  [ '999xx9', '999-XX-9' ]
];
arr.forEach(([str]) => {
  const result = str.toUpperCase()
    .replace(/\d{4}|\D{4}/, substr => `${substr.slice(0, 2)}-${substr.slice(2)}`)
    .replace(/[a-z]{4}|\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\d)/gi, '$&-');
  console.log(result);
});
```

You can also do it by matching and then joining - match 3 non-digits, or 3 digits, or 1-2 non-digits, or 1-2 digits:

```js
const arr = [
  [ 'xx9999', 'XX-99-99' ],
  [ '9999xx', '99-99-XX' ],
  [ '99xx99', '99-XX-99' ],
  [ 'xx99xx', 'XX-99-XX' ],
  [ 'xxxx99', 'XX-XX-99' ],
  [ '99xxxx', '99-XX-XX' ],
  [ '99xxx9', '99-XXX-9' ],
  [ '9xxx99', '9-XXX-99' ],
  [ 'xx999x', 'XX-999-X' ],
  [ 'x999xx', 'X-999-XX' ],
  [ 'xxx99x', 'XXX-99-X' ],
  [ 'x99xxx', 'X-99-XXX' ],
  [ '9xx999', '9-XX-999' ],
  [ '999xx9', '999-XX-9' ]
];
arr.forEach(([str]) => {
  const result = str.toUpperCase()
    .match(/[a-z]{3}|\d{3}|[a-z]{1,2}|\d{1,2}/gi)
    .join('-');
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: snippet throws an unexpected token error in Safari browser

Comment: @2x2p, where? It works fine on my end, everything in the snippet is vanilla ES6

Comment: Thank you so much, was about to add some extra info, but the first solution works exactly how I need it to.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did a backward compatibility test where `=>` is being rejected. leave it as it is, I would say as the other answer has already been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented this using `Stack`. Here is the function. You just need to pass the string to this function.

```
const convert = (str) => {
    let stack = str.split('').reduce((newArr, char, index) => {
        if(index !== 0 && newArr[newArr.length-1] !== char) {
            newArr.push('-');
            newArr.push(char);
            return newArr;
        } else {
              newArr.push(char);
              return newArr;
        }

    },[])
    return stack.join('').toUpperCase();
}
```

```js
// Here you can check this in action
const convert = (str) => {
    let stack = str.split('').reduce((newArr, char, index) => {
        if(index !== 0 && newArr[newArr.length-1] !== char) {
            newArr.push('-');
   newArr.push(char);
   return newArr;
        } else {
   newArr.push(char);
         return newArr;
  }
  
    },[])
 return stack.join('').toUpperCase();
}

const strings = [ 'xx9999','9999xx','99xx99','xx99xx','xxxx99','99xxxx','99xxx9','9xxx99','xx999x','x999xx','xxx99x','x99xxx','9xx999','999xx9',];


strings.map(string => console.log(convert(string)))
```